# When is $\exp(-iHt)$ well-defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

If $H$ is a linear operator, what restrictions should be put on $H$ in order for $\exp(-iHt)$ to be well defined?

How do you define $\exp(-iHt)$ when $H$ is infinite-dimensional? (If it is possible)

Comment: If $H$ is a bounded operator, $\exp(-iHt)$ is defined for all $t$.

Comment: However, it is worth noting that in many applications of quantum mechanics, the hamiltonian $H$ is not bounded. Indeed, $H$ is unbounded even in the prototypical example of the harmonic oscillator.

Comment: I'm not too savvy when it comes to unbounded operators, but I would imagine you would need $H$ to be self-adjoint, or at least symmetric.

Comment: $H$ being self-adjoint is certainly enough since then one can appeal to the existence of a Borel functional calculus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_functional_calculus) for $H$.

Comment: Also the case $(H-cI)^{-1}$ is bounded compact normal $X \to X$ (an Hilbert space)  helps to make things concrete (as $(H-cI)^{-1}u=\sum_j \lambda_j<u,v_j>v_j$) and see in what sense we expect convergence

Comment: @jawheele Worse: the canonical commutation relation $[x,p]=i \hbar$ implies one of $x,p$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

There is a generation theorem for a $C^0$ semigroup that answers this question if you want $t \ge 0$.

You can make sense of $e^{tA}$ for $t \ge 0$ if $A : \mathcal{D}(A)\subseteq \mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ is a closed, densely-defined linear operator whose spectrum is contained in the closed left half-plane and if
$$
            \|(A-\lambda I)^{-1}\| \le \frac{1}{\Re\lambda},\;\; \Re\lambda > 0.
$$
This can be weakened to only require that $\|(A-\lambda I)^{-n}\| \le M/(\Re\lambda)^n$ for all $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ and for some constant $M$. These conditions are essentially necessary in order to generate a $C^0$ semigroup $e^{tA}$ such that $\|e^{tA}\| \le M$ for all $t \ge 0$. (The $C^0$ requirement is that $\|e^{tA}x-x\|\rightarrow 0$ as $t\downarrow 0$ for all $x\in\mathcal{H}$.

You can recover the resolvent from the $C^0$ semigroup by the Laplace transform
$$
   \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{tA} e^{-st}x dt = (sI-A)^{-1}x,\;\; \Re\lambda > 0.
$$
You can obtain the $C^0$ semigroup from the inverse Laplace transform of the resolvent $(A-sI)^{-1}$:
$$
            e^{tA}x = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}e^{st}(sI-A)^{-1}xds,\;\; t > \gamma > 0.
$$
The construction is not simple, but it does work.